# How is a 3d perlin noise function used to generate terrain?

Tags: terrain, procedural-generation, minecraft, perlin-noise

I can wrap my head around using a 2D Perlin noise function to generate the height value but I don't understand why a 3D Perlin noise function would be used. In [Notch's blog](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1), he mentioned using a 3D Perlin noise function for the terrain generation on Minecraft. Does anyone know how that would be done and why it would be useful? If you are passing `x`, `y`, and `z` values doesn't that imply you already have the height?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, Minecraft is about Mines. So, what Notch tried to solve was: "How do I get holes / overhangs in my world?"

Since 2D perlin noise generates nice/smooth looking hills, 3d perlin noise will generate nice/smooth hills and nice holes in your 3D voxel grid.

An implementation can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20081118194515/http://peter.grumpykitty.biz/perlin.html) (while that is an N-dimensional solution).

In other use-cases the Z component of a 3D perlin noise is set to the current time. This way you will get a smooth transition between different 2d perlin noises and that can be used as groundwork for fluid textures.

Comment: The link is broken, archive.org thankfully has one snapshot from 2008: http://web.archive.org/web/20081118194515/http://peter.grumpykitty.biz/perlin.html

Comment: @Tyron Thanks! Added it to the answer text

Answer (score 44):

The article says exactly why he used 3D noise:

> I used a 2D Perlin noise heightmap...
>   ...but the disadvantage of being rather
>   dull. Specifically, there’s no way for
>   this method to generate any overhangs.
>
> So I switched the system over into a
>   similar system based off 3D Perlin
>   noise. Instead of sampling the “ground
>   height”, I treated the noise value as
>   the “density”, where anything lower
>   than 0 would be air, and anything
>   higher than or equal to 0 would be
>   ground.