# Procedural terrain generation

Tags: java, voxel

I am trying to make a 3-d java lwjgl game that stores the data in chunks and generates one chunk at a time as the player explores (infinite). How does the terrain blend between the chunks so that it is seamless?
I am stumped after researching for a long time (days, many days). Please help me!

Comment: Also, if you will have questions related to algorithms in GameDev, I think it will be more helpful to ask them on [GameDev.StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [box-based terrain generator algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm).

To make transition between boxes smooth, use small boxes upon generating your terrain.

How much small boxes should be depends on smoothness you want to achieve.

Smaller boxes lead to smoother terrain.

Comment: What about using 3-d multifractal terrain?

Comment: Use [Perlin noise algorithm for 3D-space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091468/how-is-a-3d-perlin-noise-function-used-to-generate-terrain).